# JSON и dataclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, python-3.7, dataclass

В каких моментах лучше использовать JSON, а в каких dataclasses и почему именно так? Я проводил тесты и не заметил особой разницы

Comment: JSON - это формат для сериализации данных. Он предназначен в первую очередь для сохранения данных в файл/базу или для передачи во внешние сервисы. А датаклассы нужны для того, чтобы работать с ними внутри вашей программы.

Comment: в дополнение к выше сказанному. в одном проекте я использовал и JSON и датаклассы. суть сводилась к тому, что через дата-класс я реализовал интерфейс настроек которые можно произвести в проекте, а JSON для хранения и возможности пользователем менять настройки. Так я получил удобное обращение к настройкам, четкое их описание и возможность пользователю их редактировать.

Comment: а еще мне кажется очень странным то, что люди постоянно что-то пытаются противопоставить. толстые модели или толстые view, потоки или asyncio, потоки или процессы, JSON или дата-классы, черное или белое. изучите все и примите все тогда вы сможете находить гибкие и красивые решения для любой задачи без ограничения из-за своего стремления к когнитивной легкости